# Parse non standard xml with PHP

Tags: php, xml

I have this xml-like string coming from a SOAP call:

```xml
<GSSchedule schemaVersion="3.1.0.0" xmlns:gs_pe="PEContentSchemaGS" xmlns:gs_sl="SLContentSchemaGS" xmlns:gs_s="SongSchemaGS" xmlns:gs_l="LinkSchemaGS" xmlns:gs_b="BreakSchemaGS" xmlns:gs_n="NoteSchemaGS" xmlns:gs_err="OperationStatusSchemaGS" xmlns:gs_spot="SpotSchemaGS" xmlns:gs_control="ControlSchemaGS" xmlns:gs_pol="PolicySchemaGS" xmlns:gs_syncpol="SynchronizationPolicySchemaGS" xmlns="ScheduleSchemaGS">
    <Day scheduledDate="2020-04-24">
        <Hour scheduledTime="10:00:00" publicationStatus="" />
        <Event entryType="ExactTimeMarker" entryID="1" status="Happened" timing="None" chain="Overlap" airDate="2020-04-24" airTime="10:00:00" cumulativeAirTime="2020-04-24T10:00:00" duration="0" runtime="0" skip="false" external="false" dontCopyPosition="false" fixedPosition="false" scheduledTime="10:00:00" startOffset="0" editCode="0" failureCode="0" fileName="" unscheduledCategoryGroup="" guid="84acfcc0-a580-ea11-87c8-000c29a54856" runtimeOverride="" intro1Override="" intro2Override="" intro3Override="" earlyNextToPlayOverride="">
            <EventInfo>
                <ThirdParty type="GS">11111</ThirdParty>
            </EventInfo>
            <TimeMarker type="Soft" />
        </Event>
        <Event entryType="Song" entryID="24955" status="Happened" timing="None" chain="Overlap" airDate="2020-04-24" airTime="10:00:21" cumulativeAirTime="2020-04-24T10:00:00" duration="2228.28" runtime="2228.19" skip="false" external="false" dontCopyPosition="false" fixedPosition="false" scheduledTime="10:00:00" startOffset="0" editCode="8" failureCode="0" fileName="" unscheduledCategoryGroup="" guid="517a9ac1-500b-4dfd-8886-186a8a68167d" runtimeOverride="" intro1Override="" intro2Override="" intro3Override="" earlyNextToPlayOverride="">
            <EventInfo />
            <ProgramElement>
                <gs_s:Song internalID="24955" category="Rl" categoryGroup="Rock Live" dateAdded="2019-09-27T08:59:17" lastEdited="2020-04-23T10:15:49" startDate="" endDate="" startTime="" endTime="" stopset="false" bed="None" live="false" splitBehavior="None" guid="e9c2cc4b-0783-4b9d-a4ba-4928edec1312">
                    <gs_s:Title name="Radio - Aprile 2020" internalID="40251" />
                    <gs_s:Artist name="Giovanni" internalID="7572">
                        <gs_s:ArtistCodes>
                            <gs_s:Participants>
                                <gs_s:Vocalist name="Giovanni" />
                            </gs_s:Participants>
                        </gs_s:ArtistCodes>
                    </gs_s:Artist>
                    <gs_s:AlternateCategories />
                    <gs_s:Album name="MyRadio" internalID="111" />
                    <gs_s:SongGroup name="" />
                    <gs_s:FilmName name="" />
                    <gs_pe:Changes lastPlayDate="2020-04-24" lastPlayTime="14:02:12" lastEditedDateTime="2020-04-23T10:15:49" lastStationEditedDateTime="2019-09-27T08:59:17" dateActivated="2019-09-27T08:59:17" totalPlays="15" enteredCategory="2019-09-27T08:59:17" playsInCategory="0" />
                    <gs_pe:Media ID="" fileName="\\mysrv\mystore\Audio\92\92860~RFF_8_apr2020.mp3" trimStart="0.02" trimEnd="2228.27" hookStart="" hookEnd="" intro1="" intro2="" intro3="" opening="" ending="" totalTime="2228.25" runtime="2228.19" mediaExternal="false" earlyNextToPlay="" bpmIn="" bpmOut="" bpmOverall="" />
                    <gs_pe:HourRestriction action="unban" />
                    <gs_sl:Additional publisher="" isrc="" license="" label="" recordNumber="" promoter="" country="" association="" prefix="" suffix="" />
                    <gs_sl:UserDefined userDefined1="" userDefined2="" userDefined3="" userDefined4="" userDefined5="" userDefined6="" userDefined7="" userDefined8="" userDefined9="" userDefined10="" />
                </gs_s:Song>
            </ProgramElement>
        </Event>

    </Day>
    <IsExportError>False</IsExportError>
</GSSchedule>
```

I would like to traverse the structure and get the value of the `//Day/Event/ProgramElement/gs_s:Song/gs_s:Title` node in PHP.

I tried to parse like a normal xml, with that:

```php
<?php
$rawxml = "<GSSchedule [...]"; // The string pasted above
$xmlDoc = @new \SimpleXMLElement( $rawxml );
```

(*Better elaboration based on comments*) But, when I try to `var_dump` the response, I have a strange (for me) response. With no data for the node I'm looking for

```php
object(SimpleXMLElement)#1 (3) {
  ["@attributes"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["schemaVersion"]=>
    string(7) "3.1.0.0"
  }
  ["Day"]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#2 (3) {
    ["@attributes"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["scheduledDate"]=>
      string(10) "2020-04-24"
    }
    ["Hour"]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#3 (1) {
      ["@attributes"]=>
      array(2) {
        ["scheduledTime"]=>
        string(8) "10:00:00"
        ["publicationStatus"]=>
        string(0) ""
      }
    }
    ["Event"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      object(SimpleXMLElement)#4 (3) {
        ["@attributes"]=>
        array(26) {
          ["entryType"]=>
          string(15) "ExactTimeMarker"
          ["entryID"]=>
          string(1) "1"
          ["status"]=>
          string(8) "Happened"
          ["timing"]=>
          string(4) "None"
          ["chain"]=>
          string(7) "Overlap"
          ["airDate"]=>
          string(10) "2020-04-24"
          ["airTime"]=>
          string(8) "10:00:00"
          ["cumulativeAirTime"]=>
          string(19) "2020-04-24T10:00:00"
          ["duration"]=>
          string(1) "0"
          ["runtime"]=>
          string(1) "0"
          ["skip"]=>
          string(5) "false"
          ["external"]=>
          string(5) "false"
          ["dontCopyPosition"]=>
          string(5) "false"
          ["fixedPosition"]=>
          string(5) "false"
          ["scheduledTime"]=>
          string(8) "10:00:00"
          ["startOffset"]=>
          string(1) "0"
          ["editCode"]=>
          string(1) "0"
          ["failureCode"]=>
          string(1) "0"
          ["fileName"]=>
          string(0) ""
          ["unscheduledCategoryGroup"]=>
          string(0) ""
          ["guid"]=>
          string(36) "84acfcc0-a580-ea11-87c8-000c29a54856"
          ["runtimeOverride"]=>
          string(0) ""
          ["intro1Override"]=>
          string(0) ""
          ["intro2Override"]=>
          string(0) ""
          ["intro3Override"]=>
          string(0) ""
          ["earlyNextToPlayOverride"]=>
          string(0) ""
        }
        ["EventInfo"]=>
        object(SimpleXMLElement)#6 (1) {
          ["ThirdParty"]=>
          string(5) "82454"
        }
        ["TimeMarker"]=>
        object(SimpleXMLElement)#7 (1) {
          ["@attributes"]=>
          array(1) {
            ["type"]=>
            string(4) "Soft"
          }
        }
      }
      [1]=>
      object(SimpleXMLElement)#5 (3) {
        ["@attributes"]=>
        array(26) {
          ["entryType"]=>
          string(4) "Song"
          ["entryID"]=>
          string(5) "24955"
          ["status"]=>
          string(8) "Happened"
          ["timing"]=>
          string(4) "None"
          ["chain"]=>
          string(7) "Overlap"
          ["airDate"]=>
          string(10) "2020-04-24"
          ["airTime"]=>
          string(8) "10:00:21"
          ["cumulativeAirTime"]=>
          string(19) "2020-04-24T10:00:00"
          ["duration"]=>
          string(7) "2228.28"
          ["runtime"]=>
          string(7) "2228.19"
          ["skip"]=>
          string(5) "false"
          ["external"]=>
          string(5) "false"
          ["dontCopyPosition"]=>
          string(5) "false"
          ["fixedPosition"]=>
          string(5) "false"
          ["scheduledTime"]=>
          string(8) "10:00:00"
          ["startOffset"]=>
          string(1) "0"
          ["editCode"]=>
          string(1) "8"
          ["failureCode"]=>
          string(1) "0"
          ["fileName"]=>
          string(0) ""
          ["unscheduledCategoryGroup"]=>
          string(0) ""
          ["guid"]=>
          string(36) "517a9ac1-500b-4dfd-8886-186a8a68167d"
          ["runtimeOverride"]=>
          string(0) ""
          ["intro1Override"]=>
          string(0) ""
          ["intro2Override"]=>
          string(0) ""
          ["intro3Override"]=>
          string(0) ""
          ["earlyNextToPlayOverride"]=>
          string(0) ""
        }
        ["EventInfo"]=>
        object(SimpleXMLElement)#7 (0) {
        }
        ["ProgramElement"]=>
        object(SimpleXMLElement)#6 (0) {
        }
      }
    }
  }
  ["IsExportError"]=>
  string(5) "False"
}
```

Could someone help me to figure out what code I should use?

Comment: Tools like SimpleXMLElement are not meant to handle SOAP. There are dedicated libraries and tools for that. You should start by using them.

Comment: Hard to debug a "strange response" when you don't tell us what the response is. The file looks like well-formed XML, I don't know why you describe it as "XML-like". Obviously if you paste it into a string literal in some host language you will have to escape the double quotes.

Comment: After your above code, you can access the data using `echo $xmlDoc->children("")->Day->Hour->asXML();`, so not sure (besides the slightly dodgy namespaces) you have?

Comment: @NigelRen You might be right (seeing the error message would be so helpful!!) but the vast majority of XML tools allow any string to be used as a namespace name (The namespaces spec is weirdly ambiguous about this: it talks throughout of namespaces being URIs, but it's not part of the definition of namespace well-formedness in section 7, and not part of processor conformance in section 8 - and that was a deliberate decision.) In any case these are valid relative URIs, which according to §2.2 are deprecated but not disallowed.

Comment: @MichaelKay, they will output warnings (which may be the *strange* response), but the code does work.  Just have to wait to see what OP was expecting.